# ViewSet.list() got an unexpected keyword argument - Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, djangorestframework

Tengo un problema para definir la url de mi api en django rest framework

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers

from app.barrios.views import *

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('', BarrioViewSet, basename='barrio')
router.register('(?P<bpk>\d+)/metadatas', BarrioMetadataViewSet, basename='barrio-metadata')

urlpatterns = [
    path('municipios/<int:pk>/barrios/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

en la linea donde esta definido `BarrioMedatadataViewSet` me genera el siguiente error

```
TypeError at /api/municipios/1/barrios/1/metadatas/
BarrioMetadataViewSet.list() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bpk'
```

Ya he probado cambiando diferentes maneras el register, he intentado con `<int:bpk>`
también he separado el rounter creando uno nuevo pero sigo sin resultados

¿Como puedo solucionar este problema?

#### ACTULIZACION:

Tomando en cuenta que para registrar un router con expresiones regulares debo hacer uso de la clase `ModelViewSet`
¿Qué diferencias existen entre estas como para que la clase `ViewSet` no acepte expresiones regulares?

Answer (score 0):

Logré solucionar cambiando la extensión de mi `BarrioMetadataViewset(models.ViewSet)` a `BarrioMetadataViewSet(models.ModelViewSet)`

```
class BarrioMetadataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
serializer_class = BarrioMetadataSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    return BarrioMetadataModel.objects.filter(barrio=self.kwargs.get('bpk'))

# def list(self, request, pk=None):
#     queryset = BarrioMetadataModel.objects.all()
#     queryset_serializer = BarrioMetadataSerializer(queryset, many=True)

#     return Response(queryset_serializer.data)

# def retrieve(self, request):
#     # queryset = BarrioMetadataModel.objects.all()
#     # metadata = get_object_or_404(queryset, )
#     # queryset_serializer = BarrioMetadataSerializer(metadata)

#     # return Response(queryset_serializer.data)
#     return Response("hola")
```

Pero esto me genera nuevas preguntas ¿Por qué funciona en con la clase de `ModelViewSet` y no con `ViewSet`?

Comment: Tienes razón, acabo de actualizar un poco la pregunta por esta nueva duda